# Angular CORS works with $http but not with $resource

Tags: angularjs, cors

I am new to angular, using v1.6, I have implemented a basic service for GET requests to communicate with Jetty service on a different host.

After annotating my service endpoints with CrossBorderResourceSharing. I am able to use $http without issues and I can seen the CORS flag in chrome debugger as well.

However $resource does not work gives the CORS error and does not show the CORS flag in debugger either , I am not using any custom settings for both just the basic call.

Let me know if sharing code snippet would help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable CORS in the server endpoint.
Add the following to your `WEB-INF/web.xml`

```
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

Comment: I am using embedded Jetty, cxf, spring 4, I don't have a web.xml. Since $http is working, I am doubting if the issue is with UI

Comment: CORS issue is always related to server. I doubt that there should not be any such cases where CORS error appear for $resource and not for $http.

Comment: That's what is surprising me $http works perfectly, same service when called via $resource throws CORS